# Triple link in a 5-sphere -- Proposal

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds, intersection-theory, surgery-theory

In this post I would like to propose a triple link in a 5-sphere.

Let us start with the following gluing into a 5-sphere:
$$S^5=(D^2_{} \times T^3_{}) \cup_{T^4} ({S^5 \smallsetminus D^2 \times T^3})$$

I write $(D^2_{} \times T^3_{})=D^2_{rw} \times T^3_{xyz}$.

- We denote the meridian as the $S^1_w$ (the boundary of the disk factor $D^2_{rw}$)
- We denote the longitude $S^1_x,S^1_y,S^1_z$ from the $T^3_{xyz}$.

I propose a triple link 
$$\text{Tlk}(\Sigma^3_W,\Sigma^2_U,\Sigma^2_U{'})$$ 
in a 5-sphere $S^5$, in my proposal that

$\bullet$ $\Sigma^3_W$ is insertion along the ${H_3}(D^2 \times T^3,\mathbb Z) =\mathbb Z.$

We can choose  $T^3_{xyz}$ for ${H_3}(D^2 \times T^3,\mathbb Z) =\mathbb Z$.

$\bullet$ $\Sigma^2_U$ and ${\Sigma^2_U}'$ are two insertions along the $\mathbb Z^2$ subgroups of $H_2({S^5  \smallsetminus D^2 \times T^3},\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z^3$.

For ${H_2}(D^2 \times T^3,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z^3$, with $xy$, $yz$, $zx$ 2-torus written as $T^2_{xy}, T^2_{yz}, T^2_{zx}$,

I write the Alexander-dual 2-torus in the complement space in ${S^5 \smallsetminus D^2 \times T^3}$ generating $H_2({S^5 \smallsetminus D^2 \times T^3},\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z^3$ 
 as:
$zw$, $xw$, $yw$ of three 2-torus:  $T^2_{zw}, T^2_{xw}, T^2_{yw}$.

> **My question/proposal**: Is this true that 
>   the following defining a nontrivial link invariant Tlk by the intersecting number $\#$:
>   $$
> {\#(V^4_W\cap V^3_U\cap V^3_U{'})}
> =\text{Tlk}(\Sigma^3_W=T^3_{xyz}, \Sigma^2_U=T^2_{xw}, \Sigma^2_U{'}= T^2_{yw})= \pm 1 ?
> $$
>   if I design the submanifold insertions $T^2$ and $T^3$ along the $H_2$ and $H_3$ described above?

- Here $V^4_W, V^3_U, V^3_U{'}$ are the Seifert volumes (in 4,3,3 dims) bounded by the surfaces $\Sigma^3_W,\Sigma^2_U,\Sigma^2_U{'}$ (in 3,2,2 dims).

> **My question 2**: I have not yet found related literature about this link invariant. Are there existing pieces of literature that I was not aware of but should I pay attention? Please give Refs. Can the linking form http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Linking_form provide any useful information for my proposal above?

Thank you for your feedback and encouragement!